How to add a <relative /> tag to parent POM?
In OpenRewrite you can add a comment to a POM like this. You can replace a dependency like this. But how do you add an element to an XML element such as:
<parent>
  <groupId>abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>def</artifactId>
  <version>123</version>
</parent>

Adding a <relativePath>:
<parent>
  <groupId>abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>def</artifactId>
  <version>123</version>
  <relativePath>./</relativePath>
</parent>

Is this possible?

A relative path for a dependency does not make sense at all. Why do you like to add something like that to a dependency?

Sorry corrected the text

Why do you like to add the relative with . does not really make sense? What is the purpose of that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

You can add tags to specific paths using the AddOrUpdateChildTag recipe:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/xml/addorupdatechildtag
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.yourorg.AddOrUpdateChildTagExample
displayName: Add or update child tag example
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.xml.AddOrUpdateChildTag:
      parentXPath: /project//plugin//configuration
      newChildTag: <skip>true</skip>

That said I do share Karl Heinz' concerns about adding <relativePath>./</relativePath> in the comments above, so best to clarify if you were instead aiming to add for instance <relativePath>../</relativePath>, or <relativePath/> instead.

yeah i was typing some gibberish in the relativePath for demonstration sake. thanks for the info, that should do er
